# Pylint says my function is unused, but I import it in a different module

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

Pylint will always mark functions/constants/classes that I use in other modules (but within the same package) as "unused" if I don't use them within the same file in which they are defined. For example, if I have a package like this:

```
mypackage/
   __init__.py
   foo.py
```

and my `foo.py` contains this:

```
"""
A docstring, because I'm a good boy
"""

def bar(a: int) -> int:
    """
    Another docstring, because I'm still a good boy
    """
    return a + 1
```

... and my `__init__.py` uses it in the following way:

```
"""
Docstrings for everyone!
"""

from . import foo

print(foo.bar(12))
```

It'll highlight the definition of `foo.bar` with `W0612: Unused variable 'bar'`. I'm calling pylint with `pylint --rcfile=/path/to/my/.pylintrc --msg-template='My message template' /path/to/my/package/`, so it should be able to figure out if a different module is using a function, since it can clearly tell what attributes/methods a class defined in a different module does/does not have. How do I get it to recognize my use of functions across modules?

#### A couple of notes I forgot to add

I've also tried reworking the import statement; `from .foo import bar` gives me the same problems.
If it matters, I'm running Python-3.6.3 distributed with Anaconda on MacOSX High Sierra.
Also, to clarify, I am not interested in just disabling W0612, I want it to let me know when I'm not using things, but it needs to take into account the entire package when considering usage numbers.

Comment: Check if code which imports your function is included into python environment that is used to run pylint. If __init__.py is not in PYTHONPATH directory then pylint run from system may not see imports...

Comment: @JakubGórzyński It's properly doing type checking across modules (e.g. `foo.Bar object has no member 'fizz', maybe you meant 'buzz'?`) So I know it can see things that are imported. Besides that, the directory I'm pointing it to is a valid python package (it has an `__init__.py` file), so it should be able to figure everything out from there.